# How to use gpio from device tree in a i2c_driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, i2c, gpio, device-tree

I've written an I2C driver. I want to make the GPIO which it uses configurable from the device tree.

My device tree entry is currently:

```dts
&i2c1 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c1>;
    status = "okay";
    ...
    myi2c: myi2c@43 {
        compatible = "fsl,myi2c";
        reg = <0x43>;
    };
```

I'd like to add this line into the myi2c stanza:

```dts
        myi2c-gpios = <&gpio4 29 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
```

I can see [how to do this](https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/How_to_control_a_GPIO_in_kernel_space), if I was writing a platform driver:

```c
static int gpio_init_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
   int i = 0;

   printk("GPIO example init\n");

   /* "greenled" label is matching the device tree declaration. OUT_LOW is the value at init */
   green = devm_gpiod_get(&pdev->dev, "greenled", GPIOD_OUT_LOW);
```

but in my driver's `i2c_probe()`, I have no access to a `struct platform_device *`:

```c
static int myi2c_i2c_probe(struct i2c_client *i2c, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
```

How can I read the value of `myi2c-gpios` from the device tree and use it in my i2c driver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this driver to use as an example:

```c
static int sn65dsi84_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
    ...
    struct gpio_desc *enable_gpio;

    enable_gpio = devm_gpiod_get_optional(&client->dev, "enable", GPIOD_OUT_HIGH);
    if (enable_gpio)
        gpiod_set_value_cansleep(enable_gpio, 1);
```

and its device tree is:

```dts
&i2c2 {
    clock-frequency = <100000>;
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_i2c2>;
    status = "okay";

    dsi_lvds_bridge: sn65dsi84@2c {
        status = "disabled";
        reg = <0x2c>;
        compatible = "ti,sn65dsi84";
        enable-gpios = <&gpio4 28 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
```

So `devm_gpiod_get_optional()` seems to be the answer.

Comment: You are talking about `devm_gpiod_get()` in the Q and about `devm_gpiod_get_optional()` in the A. I hole you are aware that they are slightly different.